# Trigger scheduled build if there is any change in subversion

Tags: jenkins

Now in my current setup builds are triggered daily at 6 AM. I want to change it little bit as follows: Build should be triggered daily at 6 AM, if there exists any commit in subversion.
Please explain me how to do this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the job configuration:

Build trigger -> Poll SCM -> "0 6 * * *"

Comment: @rcomblem Will it check the svn changes after successful of build?

Comment: @rcomblem I did not commit anything into SVN after the daily build but i get build today

Comment: This is meant to watch svn and trigger the build only if there is a change in svn, I've been using that with plenty of projects with check every other minute, and it just works. Don't you have something else configured in the Build trigger section of the job ?

Comment: No i did not configure anything in the Build Trigger section. Poll SCM option only selected.

Comment: I found that externals make some logs so build get triggered. Can we exclude external?

Comment: There is an "ignore externals" option in "Source code management"/"Subversion". If you check this, you won't have your external dependencies in your checkout anymore. If you want to have your externals, but not trigger when the externals have changed, create another job on the same svn path, use the "ignore externals" flag, put the poll scm option and trigger your original job as only outcome of that new job.

Comment: But i could not get "ignore externals" flag at UI